# Python get count of words in a file

Tags: python, counter

I am trying to read the words in a File looks its not working as expected. Can you please let me know if I am missing anything.

```
from collections import Counter

wordcount=Counter(f1.read())

for k,v in wordcount.items():
    print (k ,v)
```

File contents are:

```
DELETE
INSERT
DELETE
INSERT
UPDATE
UPDATE
```

Expecting

```
DELETE  2
INSERT 2 ..
```

..

but it is counting the letters

Comment: Counter will count the letters, better create a list of words and then apply Counter.

Comment: You can achieve that using readlines, or splitting the lines using a specific delimeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.readlines()`

`.read()` return char continuously. so Counter counts the char.
but `.readlines()` return word(The fact is a line, but in your case, a word in a line)

Answer (score 1):

> Use [**readlines()**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) instead of read,

```
from collections import Counter

f1 = open("test.txt", "r")
wordcount=Counter(f1.readlines())

#print(wordcount)

for k,v in wordcount.items():
    print (k ,v)
```

To get better result use split() or splitlines() to remove `\n`

```
wordcount=Counter(f1.readlines().splitlines())
# or
wordcount=Counter(f1.read().split())
```

Output:

```
DELETE 2
INSERT 2
UPDATE 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `readlines()` instead of `read()`. Also you need to get rid of `\n` characters as well since using `readlines()` will read them as well.

```
from collections import Counter

with open('chk.txt') as f:
    mylist = f.read().splitlines()   #get rid of newline character

wordcount=Counter(mylist)

for k,v in wordcount.items():
    print (k ,v)

#Output:
('INSERT', 2)
('UPDATE', 2)
('DELETE', 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your argument for Counter.
From

```
wordcount=Counter(f1.read())
```

To

```
wordcount=Counter(f1.readlines().split())
```